# RPI Python Mqtt 99% cpu

Tags: python

Had a  go at having my button send mqtt messages when pushed. It works great, but its hogging the cpu of this pooor pi. Im having trouble seeing why, could anyone point me in the right direction? :)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

pinList = [6]

for i in pinList:
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)

while True:
input_state = GPIO.input(17)
if input_state == False:
    print('Button Pressed')
    publish.single("/home/relay_channel4/1", "ON", hostname="localhost")
    time.sleep(12)
    publish.single("/home/relay_channel4/1", "OFF", hostname="localhost")
```

Comment: did you try adding a small time.sleep in your while True loop?

Comment: Please make sure your indentation is correct.

Comment: I have a time.sleep in there - is that not right? Also seems to me my indentation is correct. Would it even run if it wasnt?

Comment: Ah, thanks Chris. You were correct. Adding the time.sleep did the trick